# Child relationship?

Tags: force.com, lookup

I have a custom object.  I wish to create a look up relationship from it to an Opportunity. 
When I specify the relationship details, I enter Error DM_Daily_Digests5 for the Child Relationship Name

I get

```
There is already a Child Relationship named DM_Daily_Digests5 on Opportunity.
```

I want to find out more about this child relationship which got in by accident so I can delete it.  I go to Opportunity but see nothing. Any ideas how I can find out more about it and delete it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must already have a relationship in place from DM_Daily_Digest to Opportunity. You would need to find this relationship on the DM_Daily_Digest object and review there rather than on Opportunity.

If you can't find this relationship on the DM_Daily_Digest object, is it possible that the relationship could be on another Object and named incorrectly?

You could use the Force.com IDE to examine the relationship from the Opportunity and confirm which child object it is referring to, e.g. (showing sample custom object).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have the Force.com perspective open in Eclipse but can't find that view. Is the screen shot from a separate tool or view? I was able to figure out the answer looking at the XML of the objects but would still be interested in figuring out where you can see what you have shown.

Comment: @dublintech if you look in your project in Package Explorer (in Eclipse), you will see at the bottom salesforce.schema. Double-click that, and it will open the view I referenced.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by a deleted field/object that's still in the recycle bin. Salesforce won't let you deploy an object/field to an org if the org has an object/field with the same name, even if it's been deleted. You must permanently delete or "erase" the deleted item before you can deploy one with the same name.